# Using AJAX without duplicating the output files

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using WordPress and I have a shortcode which displays some blog posts. To display these has a lot of lines of code. I know that AJAX I can specify the file that I want to use and the only way that I've done this in the past is to basically duplicate the data display portion of the file so it populates the div correctly.

This maybe a stupid question but is there an easier way so that I don't have to duplicate the file content. Since this is a shortcode in WordPress I don't think I can it as a function to display the output.

I did try this:
I'm just doing some testing and the shortcode function looks like this:

```
function blog_shortcode_by_zip($atts) {
    display_blog_shortcode($atts);
}
```

I then have this function defined further down the page:

```
function display_blog_shortcode($atts){
    echo "it works";
    echo '<a href="google.com" id="click_me">ljasfdj</a>';
    echo '<div id="display_here"></div>';
}
```

This works fine and displays the data correctly. I know have an AJAX function that I'm trying to call the same function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_show_blog', 'show_blog');
function show_blog() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
    diplay_blog_shortcode('value');
}
```

However, when I do execute this, AJAX comes back with a fatal error and says that the `display_blog_shortcode` is not defined. How does it work within the file but not using AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a WP shortcode you can apply `the_content` filter to content which contains the shortcode -- this will trigger your shortcode handler and will replace the shortcode with the full output.

You can use this outside of the post content, as part of your AJAX call.

The PHP file that your AJAX calls might contain something like:

```
<?php

// If you use this code outside of WordPress, you'll need to pull in WP core
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

$content = '[YOURSHORTCODE]';
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

echo $content;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This works good actually. The only issue is that images are not displayed. The response only outputs text. How can I also get images to be displayed too?

Comment: The images are actually returned in the HTML but they aren't displayed. Some of the other formatting is also lost I noticed.

Comment: You probably need to run additional formatting filters... let me check for what they are.

Comment: Well I looked, but they are hooked into the_content already. Can you view source and tell me what type of differences between your actual shortcode and what's returned in the example? Maybe we can sort out what's missing.

Comment: I see what my issue is. The original output has some added styles which looks like it was caused by a flexslider plugin. I'm also using the isotope plugin which looks like it doesn't re-trigger those styles as well.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I had to call the load function again because there was some JS that needed triggering again. Thanks for the suggestion!